# How to close a particular windows explorer window in c#?

Tags: c#

I am wondering if I can close an explorer window which is communicating with my USB drive. I can get the removable disk and its drive letter by using

```
DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
{
    if (!drive.IsReady)
    {
        continue;
    }

    if (drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && isDirectoryEmpty(drive.Name) == true)
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

How do I do that ? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13501771/closing-a-specific-instance-of-windows-explorer might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"))
{
  if (p.MainWindowTitle.ToLower().Contains(@"yourSpecificWindow"))
  { 
    p.Kill();
  }
}
```

Comment: This cannot works. There is only one explorer process with an empty `MainWindowTitle`, even if you have several explorer windows.... And if you kill explorer, the window task bar is killed too.... See my answer

Comment: This works as someMain windowtitke are not empty. Try opening documents window.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer")` because there is always one `explorer` process in the returned array, and by killing it, you would kill the window task bar too.

You have to use a COM library as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13464352/1280523